# How to combine two foreach to one in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one function which is having some logic which have 2 foreach loop but i want to make code compact so I am trying to use compactmap

```
func getData() -> [String] {
        var ids = [String]()
        self.item?.connections?.forEach { connection in
            connection.validLine?.forEach { line in
                if let _ = line.connection?.links[LinkKey.dataGroups],
                   let dataGroups = line.dataGroupsCache, dataGroups.isContinue {
                    ids += checkinGroups.connections?.compactMap { $0.id } ?? []
                }
            }
        }
    return ids
}
```

so instead of 2 foreach i am trying to make in one by using         `self.item?.connections?.compactMap({ $0.validline })` but I am getting error saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Can you share the `item` Struct including its properties?

Comment: What happens if you "guard let" away the optionality of self.item?.connections? so that you have an honest array of connection's first

Comment: Frankly, given that you never append any items into the `ids` return value, just `return []` is all you need. I think you should post a compilable example.

Comment: If you want to simplify this code, I'd start by getting rid of all the optional arrays. If a "nil" array and an "empty" array are the same thing, then it shouldn't have been an optional in the first place. Then switch to simpler `for-in` rather than the tricky `.forEach` to get your code correct (which will get rid of a lot of the confusing type errors). And then from there you can possibly simplify to flatMap if it turns out the loop matches that meaning. But first, you have way too many optionals here, and it makes the code very hard.

Comment: @DanielT. yes..sorry it was by mistake typo in name..corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can do it without to `forEach` or `compactMap`. Here is a possible solution:

```
func getData() -> [String] {
    return item?.connections?.compactMap { connection in
        connection.validLine?.compactMap { line in
            guard let _ = line.connection?.links[LinkKey.dataGroups], line.dataGroupsCache?.isContinue == true else { return nil }
            return checkinGroups.connections?.compactMap(\.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a translation of your post into something that is compilable and a direct translation into a version that doesn't use forEach.

I changed `connectionIds` to `ids` in your example because otherwise, you might as well just return `[]`.

```
class Example {
    func getData() -> [String] {
        var ids = [String]()
        self.item?.connections?.forEach { connection in
            connection.validLine?.forEach { line in
                if let _ = line.connection?.links[LinkKey.dataGroups],
                   let dataGroups = line.dataGroupsCache, dataGroups.isContinue {
                    ids += checkinGroups.connections?.compactMap { $0.id } ?? []
                }
            }
        }
        return ids
    }

    func getDataʹ() -> [String] {
        guard let connections = item?.connections else { return [] }
        let numberOfProperLines = connections.flatMap { $0.validLine ?? [] }
            .filter { line in
                if let _ = line.connection?.links[LinkKey.dataGroups],
                   let dataGroups = line.dataGroupsCache, dataGroups.isContinue {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            .count

        return (0..<numberOfProperLines).flatMap { _ in checkinGroups.connections?.compactMap(\.id) ?? [] }
    }

    var checkinGroups: CheckInGroups!
    var item: Item!
}

enum LinkKey: Int {
    case dataGroups
}
struct Item {
    let connections: [Connection]?
}

struct Connection {
    let id: String?
    let validLine: [Line]?
    let links: [LinkKey: Void]
}

struct Line {
    let dataGroupsCache: DataGroups?
    let connection: Connection?
}

struct DataGroups {
    let isContinue: Bool
}

struct CheckInGroups {
    let connections: [Connection]?
}
```

Comment: That said, this code doesn't make a whole lot of sense out of context. Why would you want multiple copies of the same ideas from `checkinGroups`?